# Embedding The Quotient Code

Tags: coding-theory

A *quotient code* is the linear quotient $\frac {B}{A}$ of two binary linear codes equipped with the usual quotient norm $||\space||$ defined by $||b+A||=min_{a\in A}{||b+a||}$. Show that for some $n\in \Bbb N$ the quotient code $\frac {B}{A}$ is embedded in $\Bbb F_2^n$ via linear isometry.

Edit (lifted from a comment, JL):  The term "quotient code" given here is being defined here – not imported from some other unnamed source to the very best of my knowledge. Quotient spaces are useful in coding theoretic arguments, and have been used by many including Slepian. The idea was a simple late night musing in coding theory

Comment: This question needs a source. My answer may be a bit unexpected, but I won't post it without you giving a bit of context. See [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: @Jyrki. Thank you for the link. I checked it out and read most of it. Would you please indulge me and explain what worries you so much ? The term "quotient code" given here is being defined here not imported from some other unnamed source to the very best of my knowledge. Quotient spaces are useful in coding theoretic arguments and have been used by many including Slepian. The idea was a simple late night musing in coding theory. I have composed a proof now but I am also interested in other approaches.

Comment: I was worried about it being a homework assignment. Mostly because this claim is false.

Comment: No, it's definitely not a homework assignment.

Comment: Editing the post to make the question clearer and more convincing.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is patently false. For a counterexample let $B$ be the universal code of length $7$, and let $A$ be the $(7,4,3)$ Hamming code.

Then:

- Because $A$ is a perfect single-error-correcting code, every non-trivial coset $b+A$, $b\notin A$ has a weight one coset leader.
- By the previous bullet, an isometry $\phi:B/A\to\Bbb{F}_2^m$ for some $m$ must map all the non-trivial cosets $b+A$ to words of Hamming weight one.
- If $b_1+A$ and $b_2+A$ are distinct non-trivial cosets of $A$, then $b_1+b_2+A$ is another, and should also be mapped to a word of Hamming weight one.
- But it is impossible for all three vectors $\phi(b_1+A)$, $\phi(b_2+A)$ and $\phi(b_1+b_2+A)$, the last of which must be equal to $\phi(b_1+A)+\phi(b_2+A)$, to be of weight one. That sum of two words of weight one has an even weight.

Comment: Thank you I see. Under what conditions on $A$ is the quotient $\frac {\Bbb F_2^n}{A}$ embedded in a universal code via linear isometry ?

Comment: @OliverKayende That's a more difficult question. At some point I tried to build something like a category of codes, and my attempt failed at about this point :-)  Similar problems are likely to occur, when the weight approaches the covering radius.

Comment: I started playing with the idea last week hoping it would give me some headway in my research on quadratic residue codes.

Comment: What was wrong with the other question I posted ?